# Populating on an already fetched document. Is it possible and if so, how?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a document fetched as:

```
Document
  .find(<condition>)
  .exec()
  .then(function (fetchedDocument) {
    console.log(fetchedDocument);
  });
```

Now this document has a reference to another document. But I am not populating that reference when I'm querying this document. Instead, I wanna populate it later. So is there any way of doing that? Can I do this:

```
fetchedDocument
  .populate('field')
  .exec()
  .then(function (reFetchedDocument) {
    console.log(reFetchedDocument);
  });
```

Another method I came across is to do this:

```
Document
  .find(fetchedDocument)
  .populate('field')
  .then(function (reFetchedDocument) {
    console.log(reFetchedDocument);
  });
```

Now does this re-fetch the entire document all over again or just fetch the populated part and add it in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your second example (with `Document.find(fetchedDocument)`) is highly inefficient. It's not only re-fetching the whole document from MongoDB, it's also uses all fields of previously fetched document to match against MongoDB collection (not just `_id` field). So, if some part of your document changed between two requests, this code won't find your document.

Your first example (with `fetchedDocument.populate`) is fine, except for `.exec()` part.

[`Document#populate` method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate) returns a `Document`, not a `Query`, so there is not `.exec()` method. You should use special [`.execPopulate()` method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-execPopulate) instead:

```
fetchedDocument
  .populate('field')
  .execPopulate()
  .then(function (reFetchedDocument) {
    console.log(reFetchedDocument);
  });
```

Comment: Okay, so `fetchedDocument.populate('field').exec().then(function (reFetchedDocument) {
    console.log(reFetchedDocument);
  });` will work?

Comment: Yes, it should work, except for `.exec()` part. [`Document#populate` method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate) returns a `Document`, not a `Query`, so there is not `.exec()` method. So you should use special `.execPopulate()` method instead.

Comment: @Kaylors added it to my answer.